# play audio file

Tags: android, audio, media-player

I want to play audio file after some seconds.

Suppose total length of file is 00:00 to 00:10 second.
If I want to start audio file from 00:03 to 00:10 second, how can I?

Media player should start audio file from the duration of 00:03 second to end of file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use media player seekTo method to seek media player to a specific time:

```
public void seekTo (int msec)
```